# Multithreading code testing by Spock

Tags: multithreading, groovy, spock

I want to verify exception throwing in one of my running threads. This is piece of my test code:

```
then: 
def e = thrown(RequestFormatException) 
e.message == "Incorrect first line: INCORRECT LINE"
```

When I run this I get next messages:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" by.westside.staircase.core.exception.RequestFormatException: Incorrect first line: INCORRECT LINE 
    at by.westside.staircase.core.util.HttpUtil.parseHttpRequest(HttpUtil.kt:19)
    at by.westside.staircase.core.server.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.kt:26)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Expected exception of type 'by.westside.staircase.core.exception.RequestFormatException', but no exception was thrown

    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.checkExceptionThrown(SpecInternals.java:79)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.thrownImpl(SpecInternals.java:66)
    at by.westside.staircase.core.server.SyncServerSpec.should throw exception in incorrect first line case(SyncServerSpec.groovy:26)
```

Comment: Can you come up with an example we can try?

Comment: @tim_yates you can throw exception in any thread created by new Thread(new RunnableClass()).start()

Comment: Why not test the runnable rather than a thread you've not got a reference to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spock, like JUnit, can only assert on exceptions thrown from the thread executing the test, not "any thread in the application". Your exceptions are not caught by spock, and can't be asserted.

You can play with `Thread.uncaughtExceptionHandler` but you should probably unit-test the runnable executed in your thread - or implement some error handling in your business logic, and test this part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think another option is to actually catch the exception in your test case and assert on that. here is a snippet of my code (written in Groovy Spock):

```
def exceptionThrown = false
def exceptionMessage
def thread = new Thread( {_ ->
   try{
      //code you are testing
   } catch(Exception e) { // change this to the exception you want to catch
      exceptionThrown = true
      exceptionMessage = e.getMessage()
   }
})

then: "the right exception should be thrown"
exceptionThrown
exceptionMessage = "I am thrown" //this should be your error message
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and took a simple, hokey route.  In the spirit of "good software is testable software" I added a flag and asserted on that, labeling it:  // only for testing.  Which, of course, will be ignored down the road.

Answer (score -1):

> thrown(RequestFormatException)

this should be in your first line after `then:` as this is the constraint imposed by spock.

Whenever thrown or notThrown is called in it should be the first statement.

**Note:** `thrown` and `notThrown` both return true and hence there should be no comparison operator as well.

Hence, In your case , it should be like below:

```
then: 
 thrown(RequestFormatException)
```